# Django annotate on another distinct field in queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model as follows:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    value= models.IntegerField()
    data = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

I want to make a query to return the sum of the values for every distinct data. I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
Task.objects.all().distinct('data').annotate(value = Sum('value'))
```

I was getting this error:

```
NotImplementedError: annotate() + distinct(fields) not implemented.
```

Comment: How would you know which `value`s to cosider (from the set of task with identical `data`)?

Comment: Do you need inline queryset answer ?

Comment: @LudwikTrammer: So u mean to say we cannot achieve this in a single query? DO we need to write 2 queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `values` instead of `distinct`, this will group by `data` (not sure if this is what you need).

```
Task.objects.values('data').annotate(Sum('value'))
```

An attempt with `.extra` (to select the entire object)

```
Task.objects.extra(select={'values_sum': "SELECT SUM(values) FROM myapp_task t WHERE t.data = myapp_task.data"})
```

Comment: But values will not return me the whole object right? I am trying to get the entire object. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @RogerFederer will returns only data attribute.

Comment: @RogerFederer, checkout my second example.